# Rogue code destroying the default justification--Please help

Tags: justification, structure

With my beginner's knowledge, I could identify the portion of the code responsible for the destruction of the default class justification structure (Commenting that portion removes the problem). However, as the code is lend to me by a senior, I am not being able to correct it with my limited knowledge. Please help.

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc, a4paper, 11pt, oneside, chapterprefix=true, sfdefaults=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum} % For generating dummy text
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%%%%%%%%% Header Footer begin
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,markcase=upper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{}
\setkomafont{pagefoot}{\bfseries\small}
\ohead{\headmark}
\lefoot*{\pagemark{} \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1pt}{\baselineskip} Page}
\rofoot*{Page \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1pt}{\baselineskip} \pagemark}
\ifoot*{MAKAUT, WB}
\AddToHook{cmd/frontmatter/after}{%
  \renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}% instead of plain → manual
  \pagestyle{empty}%
}
\AddToHook{cmd/mainmatter/after}{%
  \renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{plain}%
  \pagestyle{headings}%
}
%%%%%%%%%Header Footer End
\usepackage[pass,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % for underline with normalem option
\usepackage{ragged2e} % For justified text
%\usepackage[none]{./UbuntuFonts/ubuntu}
% Math packages
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\graphicspath{{./images/}}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mdwmath}
\usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage{euler}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
%\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{References.bib}
\usepackage{multicol}% used for the two-column index
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
%Table packages
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\footnotesize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\newenvironment{calligraphic}{\usefont{T1}{pzc}{m}{it}}{}

% Link setup
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks   = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
  urlcolor     = blue, %Colour for external hyperlinks
  linkcolor    = blue, %Colour of internal links
  citecolor   = red %Colour of citations
}

%\makeindex
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
%\pagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{page}{1}
%\include{copyright}
%*********************Suspected portion begins ***********************
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    % Top border
    \draw[line width=2pt] ($(current page.north west)+(10cm,-10cm)$) -- ($(current page.north east)+(-10cm,-10cm)$);

    % Bottom border
    \draw[line width=2pt] ($(current page.south west)+(10cm,10cm)$) -- ($(current page.south east)+(-10cm,10cm)$);

    % Text
    \node[align=center, text width=\textwidth, font=\fontsize{30}{36}\selectfont] at (current page.center) {%
    Dedicated\\In the loving memory of my father, whose unwavering encouragement and belief in my abilities have been a constant source of inspiration throughout my academic journey.};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\begin{calligraphic}
\begin{center}
    \huge \textbf{Declaration}
\end{center}
\LARGE
{I hereby declare that this dissertation is the product of my own work, and I attest that it contains no material that resulted from collaboration, except where explicitly acknowledged in the text. Furthermore, I confirm that this dissertation has not been previously submitted, either in part or in its entirety, to any other University or Institution for the purpose of obtaining any degree, diploma, or other qualification. All sources used and referenced in this dissertation are duly credited, and any borrowed ideas or information are appropriately cited in accordance with academic standards and guidelines.\\~\\~\\}

\large {
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}p{8cm}}

   &   \dotfill \\
   Date: 27-10-2023 &  \begin{center}( First LastName ) \end{center} \\

   Place: MAKAUT, WB & PhD Registration Number: XXXXXXXXXXX \\

\end{tabular}
}
\end{calligraphic}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newpage
%\pagestyle{empty}
\setstretch{1.0}
% Start a new page with custom margins and alignment
\newgeometry{left=1cm, right=1cm, top=0.5cm, bottom=0.5cm} % Set custom margins
 \Large \centering
{MAULANA ABUL KALAM AZAD UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY, WEST BENGAL\\
(Formerly WEST BENGAL UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY)\\
Main Campus: NH 12, Haringhata, Post Office - Simhat, Police Station – Haringhata, Pin - 741249\\
City Campus: BF-142, Sector -I, Salt Lake, Kolkata -700 064\\~\\}
\hrule
\vspace{1cm}
{\fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont % Set font size to 20pt with 24pt line spacing
    \textbf{\underline{Declaration regarding originality of Ph.D. Thesis}}}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Name, Designation \& Affiliation of Research Supervisor: $Dr.~ FirstName~ LastName$
  \item Name of the Ph.D Scholar: $FirstName~ LastName$
  \item Ph.D. Registration number with department:$ ~XXXXXXXX, Dept: CSE$
  \item Title of the Thesis: $The~complete~ title~ of ~the~ thesis~ as~ per~ proposal$
   \item \Large \uline{\textbf{Declaration by the Supervisor/Joint/Associate Supervisor/Research Scholar}\\~\\}
   We declare that--
            \begin{enumerate}
              \item The similarity index of the submitted thesis is 4\% (write index in percentage)
              \item This thesis/work is original and has not been submitted for the award of any other Degree / Diploma in any other University / Institutes.
              \item We have faithfully acknowledged, given credit to and referred to the already published works whenever those works have been cited in the text and the body of the thesis.
              \item We shall be responsible for any legal dispute / case(s) for violation of any provisions of the Anti-plagiarism policy / Copyright act / Piracy / Cyber/ IPR etc
              \item If in case, any of the above information is found to be false or misleading, we are aware that we will be held liable for it and Maulana Abul Kalam Azad University of Technology (MAKAUT), West Bengal can take appropriate actions against us based on UGC Notification (F.1-18/2010(CPP-II), New Delhi, the 23rd July’2018) and its subsequent modifications.
            \end{enumerate}
 \end{itemize}
 \vspace{2cm}
 \begin{tabular}{p{7cm}p{7cm}}
    \dotfill & \dotfill \\
   ( XXXXXXX, Scholar ) & (Dr.~XXXXXXX, Supervisor)\\
    Date:  & Date: \\
    Place: MAKAUT, WB & Place: MAKAUT, WB\\
\end{tabular}
\restoregeometry
%********************Suspected portion ends *******************
%\include{certificate}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
%\include{acronyms}
%\include{Acknowledgement}
%\include{Publications Related to Thesis}
\addchap{Abstract}
\lipsum[5-6]
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[5-6]
\section{Motivation}
\lipsum[3-5]
Write Motivation of the research work
\section{Contribution}
\lipsum[5-6]
Write the thesis contribution
\section{Organization of thesis}
\lipsum[2-3]
Brief description of chapters in the thesis.
\subsection{Chapter 2: Literature Survey}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Chapter 3:}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Chapter 4:}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Chapter 5:}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Chapter 6:}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Chapter 7:}
\lipsum[1-2]
%\end{justify}
\backmatter
%\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: ?? Where did you get the code from ?? It's certainly not what a beginner would write ... // Why all those unused packages ?? // For a systematic process please apply this procedure: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/651159/245790 . It converges exponentially, but doesn't free your from observing and thinking.

Comment: you have a \centering  which is not grouped. But who on earth gives you such code??

Comment: Most of the packages are used inside the chapters ( unless there is any redundancy)

Comment: be aware that commands like `\large` are switches. They do not take an argument.

Comment: One of my senior scholar, after sufficient pleading, gave me that portion of code. You know the journey of a PhD scholar is always pitiful. Now he said he can't help further.

Comment: You can't possibly be using all those packages in one document, surely????

Comment: They were assembled from my individual publications, so I guess they will be used. However, there must be some kind of optimization that can be done with similar packages, but my knowledge in this regards is poor.

Comment: don't guess! remove _all_ packages and only add ones that are needed, you only bring debugging pain and weird conflicts with code like this.

Comment: In an old answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/599545/is-this-a-junk-preamble), I gave some rough tips for how to cut down an “inherited” LaTeX template to remove unnecessary accumulated junk and keep just the core part you need and understand.

Comment: Ok, it seems I have to start doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
\Large \centering
```

on line 131 applying large centering to the entire document, change that to

```
% \Large %\centering
```

and you get:

[image]

Comment: +1 Nice : ) // And for @Bukaida: it looks like what you get when one just starts with class article and no package used ... i.e. minimal code ...

Comment: But I need the header (132-135) and the signature portion centered.

Comment: @Bukaida Well put those bits in `\begin{center}....\end{center}` as you have on line 107

Comment: Thanks David, the problem is solved. As per your suggestion, I have started chopping off the unknown packages one by one until an error is thrown. Thank you all guys.